# Get non-deleted forms from Django formset

Tags: django, django-forms, formset, inline-formset

When I use a formset that's both `can_order` and `can_delete` I'm able to get all the deleted forms with `.deleted_forms` and all the non-deleted forms (in order) with `.ordered_forms`.

If I use a formset that doesn't use `can_order` I no longer have access to `.ordered_forms` (it throws an exception).  Is there an easy way to get the list of forms that are not deleted?

The closest I can find is manually creating it with:

```py
[form for form in formset.forms if not formset._should_delete_form(form)]
```

However, that's using a "hidden" method and it seems odd there's not something already built-in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this to avoid using a "private" method:

```
[form for form in formset.forms if form not in formset.deleted_forms]
```

Comment: It's been 4 years, but I think i was specifically looking for some formset property that would be there regardless of `can_order` or `can_delete`.  This works, but only if you always know `can_delete=True`.  I guess you could test `can_delete` and if it were false then use `formset.forms` and if true then use what you've suggested.